# How to remove all of the same value from a column if a value is a certain value in another column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table. How do I remove all of a certain value from one column if that value has another value in a different column. Here is an example:

```
ID    Value
1     100
1     200
1     300
2     200
2     300
2     200
3     300
3     400
3     100
4     200
4     300
```

So I would now like to get rid of all the values with 100 in the row and display just 1 of the remaining values. So it would look like this.

```
ID    Value
2     200
4     200
```

The value on the end result does not matter, just the ID.

I hope I have explained this well.

Comment: Step 1) Write a query that returns id's having different values.

Comment: Step 2) Use that query in your delete's where clause.

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It checks if it does exist a row with same ID and Value 100, and filter accordingly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID
  FROM table_1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table_1 s
                    WHERE s.ID = t.ID
                      AND s.Value = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,MIN(Value) AS Value
FROM table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (Select Id from table1 where value=100)
GROUP BY ID
```

Output

```
ID  Value
2   200
4   200
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/190da8/17

Answer (score 0):

You should use `distinct` to get only one ID, and a subquery to exclude IDs having a value of 100.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1 T1 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT  ID
  FROM Table1 T2 
  WHERE `Value` = 100 
)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/190da8/46/0)